# Зачем разделять решение на несколько проектов?

Tags: архитектура

Заметил, что некоторые разработчики предпочитают разделять одно решение на несколько проектов, а не иметь один проект с несколькими папками. В чём преимущество или недостаток такого подхода?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слабые связи в приложении и его модульная архитектура - вещи весьма полезные. Хотя бы тем, что отдельные модули (проекты) можно использовать для других приложений, никак не относящихся к данному решению. Например, есть у вас некое десктопное приложение, работающее с базой данных. Логика работы с бд не имеет никакого отношения к визульаному интерфейсу вашей программы, и могла бы быть полезна где-то еще, а потому связывать ее намертво тоьлко с этой десктопной программой неразумно. Скажем, в какой-то момент вам покажется, что одного десктопного приложения мало, надо бы еще и веб-приложение добавить (разумеется, чтобы это веб-приложение работало с той же самой бд). Так вот в случае, если логика работы с бд у вас намертво вшита в проект с десктопным приложением, то сделать это будет не так просто. А если же она представляет собой отдельный проект, то пожалуйста - берите и пользуйтесь где угодно

Comment: Спс, я тебя наградил очком!